# Use two scrolling plugins at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery and a JS script conflicting, when they run separately they work, but when they're both running together the second one doesn't work.

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="fullpagejs/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>

<script>
// Fullpage Scroll Init
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#fullpage').fullpage({ });

// Scroll Indicator from W3Schools
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a sufficiently detailed diagnostic. Do you get errors in your JavaScript console? If you're using jQuery why not use jQuery: `$('#myBar')` instead of `getElementById` and the [`css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) function.

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: You're going to have to do some more testing to see what the problem is. Remove one. Switch the order around. Look for syntax errors. Add some `console.log` debugging or set breakpoints and step through to see how the code runs.

Comment: Tried switching them around (no fix)

Comment: Maybe `fullpage()` is incompatible with whatever that other thing is supposed to do. It's not clear from the code.

Comment: The second one is a horizontal scroll indicator that slides as you scroll

Comment: The first one is a scrolling plugin also, maybe its cause they're both scrolling plugins

Comment: They could both be trying to take over the same `onscroll` function. These may be trying to do things that the other is also trying to do, and they collide.

Comment: Not very experienced, how do i fix 'taking over the same onscroll function'?

Comment: You may need another solution, or to work to create your own custom one without the conflicts Have a look at the source of `fullpage()` to see what it does.

Comment: Both the scripts are using scrollTop